# Attempting to restart google compute instance "INVALID_FIELD_VALUE: Invalid value for field 'resource.@': '@'. Resource was not found."

Tags: cloud, cloud-computing, google, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Using the website https://console.developers.google.com, i have tried unsuccessfully to fire up an instance on the google compute engine cloud.  It stopped and started just fine months ago, but every attempt since, i have not been able to restart it.

"resource.kernel" is an example of a valid resource field.  Seems to be a blank resource name or an array of resources went missing?

```
 operation-1407990294019-5008f49527bb9-04bcda5c-f8616595

 Error  
 INVALID_FIELD_VALUE: Invalid value for field 'resource.@': '@'. Resource was not found.

 Operation type 
 reset

 Target type    
 Instances
```

```
Serial console  
Hide output


Invalid value for field 'resource.projects': 'projects/14008721509110051'.  Resource was not found.

Equivalent REST
```

## Clicking the red exclamation point (see screenshots below), a popup textbox says:
 "***The instance has been terminated and is no longer running.***"

So even though google knows the instance is definitely not started, 
the only button available via [https://console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~MyCodeWord1-MyCodeWord2-589/compute/instancesDetail/zones/us-central1-b/instances/gene?graph=GCE_CPU) is "**Reboot**".

## Screenshot 1 of 2 on exactly how it try to reboot it.

[image: console.developers.google.com]

## Screenshot 2 of 2 on exactly how it try to reboot it.

[image: The instance has been terminated and is no longer running.]

Comment: Can you give us a bit clearer description of what exactly you did to trigger this message?

Comment: @Benson, i added screenshots of what i do to try to launch the instance.

Comment: @Benson, i had also tried to launch it from gcutil, but it fails there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've pointed out, the presence of the red exclamation mark icon indicates the instance has been terminated.  Unfortunately, even though there's a reboot button present for terminated instances, it simply won't work; the backend system that handles the reboot API call requires a running instance rather than a terminated one.  In order to get the instance running again, you'll need to delete the instance (but save the disk!), and create a new instance booting from that existing disk.  This is effectively the same thing as restarting the machine, but obviously requires a little legwork.

I'll file a feature request to better deal with starting up terminated instances -- what you're doing makes sense, and I'd personally like to see the system support it directly.

Comment: I figured it was something like that, but was hoping for a more grandma fruendly system.  Linux Standards Base requires that restart of an already dead service would start the service.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware that Linux Standards Base had anything to say about the management layer of a virtual machine infrastructure. Can you point me to the right place in the doc so I may educate myself?

Comment: of course LSB has nothing to do with the management infrastructure other than i assume the infrastructure runs on Linux.  Have happened across Ubuntu and Ubuntu derivatives lately that do not conform.